# Debuging SQL queries in a Symfony2 Console Command

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I deployed a Symfony2 Console Command that runs Doctrine2 queries. I am now getting problems with the queries (when flushing the EntityManager) and would like to see the queries for debugging. So the question is simple: is there a way to debug queries executed in a console command giving similar results than the Symfony2 toolbar? Ideally, I would like to be able to see the queries in the console as well (since I am having problems only in the production server and have disabled access to the dev environment from the front controller).

Thank you!

Comment: what is the DMBS that you're using?

Comment: The DBMS is MySQL, but this information should not be determinant to answer the question IMHO (since Doctrine is using PDO). I don't want a solution based on the DBMS logs (depending on the hosting provider, you might not have logs or not have access to them). But thanks for your enquiry anyway ;-)

Comment: I ask just for suggest you to use DMBS logs ;-)

Comment: Thats what I understood from your first comment ^^

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the profiler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html) to display the queries yourself after the command has ended, or after each flush.

Comment: Ok, thats already a good insight. Is there no existing console-oriented interface to access data stored by the profiler? IMHO there should be a console equivalent to the Web Debug Toolbar... Something like php app/console profiler:requests --list --limit 10 to list the  http and console requests and then php app/console profiler:request:queries --request xxs35gsdf43...

Comment: I don't think there's a good generic solution for that in the console. Web requests are stateless: you load a page, and that's it. A command can run for a long time, spawn other commands, might not have a tty, etc. It shouldn't be much work to just display collected data from the profiler at the end of your command.

Comment: I agree with you Peter. However, I would expect similar debugging features for console commands as for http requests ;-)